# mysql/docker/cifs: innodb unable to lock persistent mount

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, cifs

I'm trying to run a mysql docker container with persistent data mapped to a folder that is mounted through CIFS.

(I orginally posted a more general question but got a bit further in terms of user rights and now the error seems to be specific to innodb/cifs mounts. Hence I'm reposting this as a new topic. Thanks for life888888 for the initial help.)

Here is the command to start the container:

```
docker run \
--name localmysql \
-v /mnt/mysqlshare:/var/lib/mysql \
--rm \
--env MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true \
-it \
mysql:8.0.31-debian
```

/mnt/mysqlshare is a mounted cifs share. The command to map the CIFS mount is below:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=linuxmount,cache=none,vers=3.0,uid=999,gid=999,rw [networkpath] /mnt/mysqlshare
```

On the machine where docker is running I have a user set up called "mysql" which is the owner of the mapped cifs drive. It is configured to have 999 as uid and group (which ties to mysql-user in the docker container which is used by default).

When remoting into the container (interactive session) and changing to "su mysql" I'm able to write into /var/lib/mysql and changes are reflected in the mounted drive.

However when starting up the container I'm getting the following error which just keeps repeating:

```
2022-12-08T21:12:56.435340Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012894] [InnoDB] Unable to open './#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0' (error: 11).
2022-12-08T21:12:56.435784Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0 error: 13
```

There's files added to the folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had that same issue on MariaDB and I'm having some success with the following (in `docker-compose.yml` file):

```
redacted-volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "cifs"
      o: "mfsymlinks,vers=3.0,username=redacted,password=redacted,uid=999,gid=999"
      device: "//192.168.4.204/docker-data/redacted/data-db"
```

`mfsymlinks` enables symlinks that MariaDB needs. `uid` and `gid` are Linux UserId and GroupId of MariaDB user that accesses the share. This works for me with Windows Server connecting to SMB shares from TrueNAS Scale. Docker version 20.10.22.

I still have this same issue with MySQL. I can't get it to work with this same configuration and I feel like I have looked everywhere on the internet.